# Selenium-Java - org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: selenium-webdriver, kubernetes, containers, devops, remotewebdriver

I am running 4 testcases in parallel at a time inside a container.

I am using Selenium-Java and the tests are running on chrome browser

Every 5/10 times I face this issue

Please let me know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it

Thanks in Advance

```
Oct 08, 2021 5:28:51 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Oct 08, 2021 5:28:52 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'COPSQE-Z02', ip: '10.153.199.20', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 94.0.4606.61, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 94.0.4606.61 (418b78f5838ed..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.JBOSqY}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:34659}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: a258a71803feba114c403046cf1...}
Session ID: a258a71803feba114c403046cf1eefef
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
    at Keywords.Repository.screenshot(Repository.java:784)
    at Keywords.TestcaseKeywords.Save(TestcaseKeywords.java:1948)
    at Keywords.TestcaseKeywords.createObject(TestcaseKeywords.java:224)
    at Keywords.TestcaseKeywords.Authoring(TestcaseKeywords.java:1003)
    at Flows.Testcase_ObjectManipulation.authoringDITA(Testcase_ObjectManipulation.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{10.129.514.85:31987, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/10.129.514.85:31987 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:208)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:237)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    ... 38 more`
```

Comment: Indicates there was a problem communicating with the browser being controlled or the Selenium server. The most common causes for this exception are:
The provided server address to RemoteWebDriver is invalid, so the connection could not be established.
The browser has died mid-test.

Comment: If there is a connection issue then how come sometimes the test pass and sometimes the browser crashes?